# SVN (source code) Installation directory in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, makefile

I needed an older version of `svn` cmd client than then one (1.9) provided by the official repositories.

So I downloaded the source code (I needed version 1.7) from [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/subversion-1.7.22.tar.bz2).

I followed the old school process of `./configure`, `make` and `make install`.

(needed to manually install missing dependencies in the mean time).

Anybody has any idea where the `svn` binary is now?

`sudo find / -name "svn" -type f` returned no results whatsoever. (apart from the source folder)

Answer (score 0):

> I needed an older version of svn cmd client than then one (1.9)
>   provided by the official repositories.

In case of Apache Subversion, you should never need an outdated version. If you think that you do -- you are doing something very wrong.